# Are hot non completing database observables a Rx usecase? Side-effect writing issue

Tags: rxjs, rx-java, reactive-programming, rx-swift

I have more of a opinions question, asi if this, what many people do, should be a Rx use case.

In apps there is usually sql database, which is queried by UI as a observable, which emits after the query is loaded + anytime data changes (Room / SqlDelight etc)

Reads sound okay, however, is it possible to have "pure" writes to the database?

Writing to the database might look like this

```
fun sync() = Completable.fromCallable {
   //  do something
   database.writeSomethingSynchronously()
}

SomeUi {
  init {
     database.someQueryObservable()
       .subscribe { show list }
   }
}
```

Imagine you want to display progressbar while this Completable is in flight.
What is effectively happening here is sideffecting to the database. Which means the opened database observable will re-emit when the data is written, but still before the sync() returns (assuming single threaded for simplicity)

Now there is point in time where there is new data in the UI and the progressbar is shown. (and worse with multithreading timings) This is invalid state.

In imperative world, sync would provide a completion callback, in which one would reload the query manually + show/hide progressbar synchronously. (And somehow block the database change listener for duration of the sync writes?)

Is there a way around this at all?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you are asking.  An observable that emits progress updates while a synchronous operation runs is fine.  There is no problem wrapping a synchronous operation with an observable that fires when the operation completes either.

Comment: @Pace the problem is that `database.write` causes `database.someQueryObservable()` to emit, before `sync()` returns; Use case is you want to show progressbar at the bottom of the list (okay rename sync() to paginate()) so that means db / ui wil lhave the new page loaded before the progressbar is removed via onComplete of the paginate completable. Let me know if its more clear, I know its hard to imagine like this;; so basically I want the db observable to wait ONLY in this case and set the data + hide progressbar at once, synchronously